# Possible to jump from new Metrics Explorer to Search?

Tags: azure-application-insights

One highly useful feature of the Classic Metrics Explorer is the ability to click the chart to jump directly to a Search blade with corresponding filters and time range already set up.

For example, if I have a Classic Metrics Explorer chart on my dashboard with Failed Requests for the last 12 hours filtered to a specific Cloud Role Name, I can click the chart to get to a dedicated blade for that chart, then click the chart on that blade (heck, I can even click-drag to easily filter time further first) to get to a Search blade which shows failed requests for the last 12 hours for that specific Cloud Role Name. This allows me with just a few clicks to easily drill down into the specific telemetry items related to anything I see in the original chart, such as traces for the failed requests.

The gif below demonstrates this, clicking on a Classic Metrics Explorer chart on the dashboard to get to its own blade, and then clicking the chart there to get to the Search blade:

[image: gif demonstrating use-case above]

This does not seem to be possible with the new Metrics explorer. Clicking a chart on the dashboard gets you to the Metrics blade for that chart, but clicking the chart there does not have any effect. See the gif below:

[image: gif demonstrating how it's not possible with the new metrics]

This means that whenever I want to drill down into some data I see on a Metrics chart/blade, I have to go to the search blade and manually set up the correct filters. When there's a high number of services, this takes significantly more time to the point of being completely out of the question, which is a shame, because the new Metrics charts are better in other ways (e.g. integration with the dashboard-wide time range).

Have I missed something, or is it simply not possible to go from the new Metrics charts to relevant telemetry items? Is there a workaround that makes the job of going from charts to related telemetry items easier when using new Metrics charts?

Comment: I can't figure it out, maybe it's missing in the new metrics chart. I asked this issue at github for assistance, refer to [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24745#issuecomment-463519663).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a [known limitation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24745#issuecomment-471900420) of the new metrics explorer.